# Why are bags considered unordered?

Tags: java, bag

Bags are stored in arrays. I do understand that we can change the size of bags as we want etc.. However, since it is stored in array, it basically has an index number isn't it? In this case, why do we still say that it is unordered?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Bags are stored in arrays

No they are not.

Actually, they *might* be, depending on *implementation*, but they surely don't have to be. It's like saying a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is stored in an array. That is e.g. true for an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), but not true for a [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

So what's the difference between a *bag*, a *list*, and a *set*?

- A **list** is *ordered*, allowing duplicates

  - Generally has slow lookup by value.
  - [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) implementation uses array, with fast lookup by position.
  - [`LinkedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) implementation uses doubly-linked nodes, with fast insert/remove at beginning of list.
- A **set** is *unordered*, no duplicates

  - Generally allows fast lookup by value.
  - [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) implementation is *unordered*.
  - [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) implementation is *ordered*.
  - [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) implementation is *sorted*.
- A **bag** is *unordered*, allowing duplicates

  - No built-in Java support. Generally just use `List` if needed.
    Recommend using third-party library if fast lookup by value is needed.

It's the *definition* of the terms that specifies the *ordered* vs *unordered* semantics. An implementation of a bag *might* happen to keep ordering, but it's not required by the generic term *bag*.

---

Let's clear up the confusion about **bags** in Java.

- The Java Runtime Library doesn't have any `Bag` type.
- The [Apache Commons Collections™](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) library has a [`Bag`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/Bag.html) interface that implements [`java.util.Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html), although it violates the `Collection` contract. It has a [`HashBag`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/HashBag.html) and a [`TreeBag`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-4.4/org/apache/commons/collections4/bag/TreeBag.html) implementation, but no implementation using an array.
- The Google [Guava](https://guava.dev/) library has a bag interface named [`Multiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) that also implements [`java.util.Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html). It has [`HashMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html), [`LinkedHashMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultiset.html), and [`TreeMultiset`](https://guava.dev/releases/16.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultiset.html) implementations, but no implementation using an array.
- [Hibernate ORM](https://hibernate.org/orm/) has a [`Bag`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Bag.html) class.

None of them specifies that a bag is a list, and none of them uses array to implement the bag.

Comment: The first point is key to the difference as Arrays and Bags are children of java.util.List, which I believe Yuan is asking for clarification. It really is just how you implement. Normally bags are found with Hibernate for queries and it is necessary to use implement a strategy. [this has a good explanation from Java.org](https://thoughts-on-java.org/association-mappings-bag-list-set/)

Comment: @Kevin *"Bags are children of java.util.List"* No they are not. The Java Runtime Library doesn't have any `Bag` type.

Comment: Whoops! you are right, I'm thinking in the context of PersistentBag which implements List. Thanks for the catch!